# Formula to extract 10 or 11 digit phone numbers from random complex test string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I a newbee in field of excel formula and need your help in a complex formula, where i need to extract phone numbers from a string of random text. This does not have a fix format for the string

Example set off strings:

```
 Dring to data add9724516002
 add 08107936777 to me pler
 8000069633 plz add. Me
 9000088106 mujhe bhi add karo dosto
```

I have already tried many formulas but nothing seem to work. Only thing fixed is the length of number, it should be either 10 digits or 11 (including initial 0)

Comment: This is not a "give me code" site, what have you tried that didn't work?  Technically, phone numbers can be up to 15 digits (I'm not sure if that includes the country codes or not) and shorter than 10.  You're also in trouble because people may include formatting, such as dashes, spaces, or parenthesis.  You may have a better time extracting all numeric characters and going from there.

Comment: Humbly suggest you revisit your earlier question [Extract pattern from column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680447) and explore some of the RegEx based solutions there. As an *enthusiast programmer* it should be a welcome challenge.

Comment: Your text looks like it'll have multiple phone numbers. If that's the case, you'll need vba code to extract them and more importantly, put them where you need them in a way they are useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a RegExp via VBA

(which seems to be coming to Excel as a formula option sometime down the track, see [uservoice](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/9022339-built-in-regex-regular-expressions-functions-to)

*code*

```
Function GetCode(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "\d{10,11}\b"
    If .test(strIn) Then
    GetCode = .Execute(strIn)(0)
    Else
       GetCode = "no match"
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If they all look like the strings you have provided above, you could use Text to Columns. Let's say all of those strings were in A1:A4.

1. Select all four cells
2. Data - "Text to Columns"
3. Delimited
4. Use "space" to separate values
5. Finish

You will now have a large majority of your phone numbers pulled out, and it will look something like this:

[image: Image Link]

(I've added a row above the data that makes every column its own set of data.. Column 1,2,3,4,5,and 6. I've also added another column in place of column A, Sort. This will be useful at a later stage)

Next, select A1:G5.

1. Click "Insert - Table"
2. "My table has headers"
3. OK

Your range is now a table, meaning you can sort the data via ascending order. I'm assuming you have hundreds of strings that you're sorting through. When you sort via ascending order, all numbers will show up first.

In the pic below I've sorted the first column of actual data, and there are two phone numbers at the top I can pull out:

[image: Image Link 2]
If you ever want to revert back to your original lineup of data, click the Sort column to "Ascending"

I hope this is a good workaround to avoid VBA. You may not get all of the phone numbers, but probably a good chunk. You can also copy and paste columns C:G to the bottom of column A and sort everything at once if you only need all of the phone numbers.

If the strings that have numbers and letters attached are similar, you can also look into the RIGHT and LEFT formulas to pull out the numbers from the alphanumeric strings